# Why is division not allowed for matrices?

Tags: matrices

Consider matrices $A$ and $B$. Suppose $AX=B.$
Can we say that $X$, if exists, is unique? If yes why can't we say that on dividing $B$ by $A$, we get $X$?

Comment: It's possible for some matrices, but not all. If $a$ and $b$ were real numbers, you can't say that if $ax = b$ has a solution for $x$, then that solution is unique (because of the case $a = 0$). Similarly, if your matrices are both the zero matrix, then any $X$ satisfies this equation.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228229/is-division-of-matrices-possible

Comment: The problem is similar to how you can't divide by zero: sometimes the function $x \mapsto Ax$ is not one-to-one, in which case such an $x$ is not necessarily unique. It is different with matrices because this can happen even when $A$ is not just the zero matrix.

Comment: Is it so because matrix multiplication is not commutative?

Comment: You also get the concept of "left division" and "right division" for matrices, for example MATLAB has two operations "/" and "\".

to Quote:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2292-matrix-division-how-does-it-work

"MATLAB interprets
>> x = A/B
as "solve the linear system x*B = A (for x)". And, similarly,
>> x = A\B
is "solve the linear system A*x = B (for x)". MATLAB will solve the system if at all possible (ie if the dimensions are consistent), giving, in general, the least-squares solution (ie minimizing the 2-norm of the residual)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is invertible, $X$ is unique, although it's $A^{-1}B$, but not in general $BA^{-1}$, which is what the notation $B/A$ might suggest. If $A$ is non-square but $A^TA$ is invertible, we instead get $X=(A^TA)^{-1}A^TB$, which would make $B/A$ even more misleading. Falling those cases, $AX=B$ doesn't have a unique solution.